# Should both spouses apply for Global Entry or TSA Precheck, or can one be a companion to the other?

Tags: global-entry, tsa-precheck

I just signed up with a travel credit card that has a benefit of an annual $100 voucher for Global Entry or TSA Precheck application fees.  My question is, should both myself and my spouse apply?  Or is it effective if the person who travels singly for work more often applies, can the other join them when traveling together?

Comment: Unfortunately, only chlidren 12 and under can accompany you through the Pre line. This was previously asked as *[Can others in my party go through TSA PreCheck?](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/56938/can-others-in-my-party-go-through-tsa-precheck)*

Comment: @choster Thanks, that was for some reason not in the first page of search on Global Entry or TSA Precheck, or recommended related questions

Comment: Yeah, the suggested matches are wonky sometimes, and not just here. I was confirming that the answer was still valid from the [Pre-Check FAQ](https://www.tsa.gov/precheck/faq) and stymied because neither *spouse* nor *companion* appears in their text.