# Does having a TSA Pre-Check member in your flight reservation increase the chances that everyone gets Pre-Check?

Tags: air-travel, tsa-precheck, travel-companions

I recently booked 4 plane tickets for the same flight for myself and three friends. I have a Known Traveler Number for TSA Pre-Check, but none of my friends do. When we printed our boarding passes at the airport, all four of us had TSA Pre-Check printed on the boarding pass. The same was true of the return flight. Was this because I had a KTN? Did it matter that I was the one who booked the reservation (i.e. if one of my friends had booked it but still entered my KTN for my ticket, would we all have gotten Pre-Check)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Who gets these is a closely guarded secret but the answers and comments on [Can others in my party go through TSA PreCheck?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/56938/4188) definitely suggest having someone with a KTN makes Pre Check happen for the others. Choice quotes:

> it seems that there is a higher likelihood of the TSA pre going to some traveling on the same record as another KTN holder.
>
> Yes, that's been my experience, as well.
>
> I have a KTN #. My wife does not and is not even a U.S. Citizen but always gets TSA Pre Check
>
> I have the exact same experience as @Dave
>
> My wife has never applied but generally gets TSA Pre on her UAL boarding pass also when we book and fly together.
>
> I have KTN and my partner does not. I have made three roundtrip flights over the last six months (domestic) and we both receive precheck on our tickets